# iPad is crashing at some point because memory increase

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

i am working on a project for both ipad and iphone and which is very older project.
my iPad is crashing at one main functionality,at that point thememory goes to 1.6 GB.
But in iphone it is working properly.please Help me in fixing this issue.
 Thank you soo much.

Comment: Can you please provide more details

Comment: actually i created new build before yesterday , if i run that build with iphone , it is working perfect.

Comment: But when it comes to iPad , when i run ,it is crashing. But iam not understanding why.   And one more thing is the old build is working properly and when i copy the recent class to old build, then old build alaso crashing

Comment: i found in left side while debugging., the memory suddenly increasing to 1.6 to 1.8 GB

Comment: It is huge memory usage! You should do profiling (by using Allocations) and find what exactly using so much memory.

Comment: May i know the procedure kirander.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been more helpful for us had you cared to provide us with more details about your hardware and the specific issue you are dealing with. But, overall it seems like a **design flaw** from the lack of enough **RAM** observed mostly on **Ipad Airs**.

In general you’re looking at a 20 - 30% increase in memory footprint when dealing with an 64-bit environments. With more apps open, including some doing work in the background, you might be seeing relatively aggressive eviction of apps from the memory.
Although things seem to have improved with newer iOS versions, the 64-bit builds of the OS still seem to run into stability issues more frequently than their 32-bit counterparts. It could just be that the move to 64-bit applications (and associated memory pressure) is putting more stress on iOS’ memory management routines, which in turn exposes some weaknesses.

- http://thehowto.wikidot.com/fix-memory-error-on-ipad

The link above might do the trick for you. Good Luck.

Comment: Thank you for response.But my iPad Air has 22.4 GB Available memory.And i run iPhone Build in IPad Only